# Core data default addXXObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Does the auto-created addXXXObject (for one\to-many relationship) automatically save the managed context? Or should I explicitly call the save method myself?

10x

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet money that it does *not* save the context.  You'll need to do that yourself.